# Using an enum as an array index in C#

Tags: c#, indexing, enums

I want to do the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404231/using-an-enum-as-an-array-index), that is:

```
enum DaysOfTheWeek {Sunday=0, Monday, Tuesday...};
string[] message_array = new string[number_of_items_at_enum];

...

Console.Write(custom_array[(int)DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday]);
```

however, I would rather have something integral to so, rather than write this error prone code. Is there a built in module in C# that does just this?

Comment: Tiny comment regarding your name "DaysOfTheWeek": The C# standard says that non-flags-style enums should have singular names and flags-style enums should have plural names, so "DayOfTheWeek" would be better. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx

Answer (score 23):

If the values of your enum items are contigious, the array method works pretty well. However, in any case, you could use `Dictionary<DayOfTheWeek, string>` (which is less performant, by the way).

Comment: That would have a significant impact on performance? How come?

Comment: @Spencer: Dictionary lookups are much slower than a direct array index (or list index).  If you're doing this a lot, it could have a noticable impact on the perf.

Comment: yes, that is the solution I chose for MouseButton, as it is a flag enum (aka 0001 right, 0010 middle, 0100 left etc). Still, pretty ugly for such a simple thing.

Comment: @Spencer: I didn't said "significant." Whether that's significant or not depends on your specific usage. Is it slower? Yes, without doubt, a Dictionary is slower than direct array lookup. Is it significant? You should benchmark and see.

Comment: The dictionary solution is preferrable if you can't prove that there's a significant impact.  Preoptimizing to array creates two problems: First it abandons the type safety of enums, making it effectively no different (but more contrived) than constants defined in a static class. Second, you end up writing more code rather than less in order to get it to behave the way you want.

Comment: this is not an answer to the question

Answer (score 12):

Since C# 7.3 it has been possible to use [`System.Enum` as a constraint on type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3#enhanced-generic-constraints). So the nasty hacks in the some of the other answers are no longer required.

Here's a very simple `ArrayByEum` class that does exactly what the question asked.

Note that it will waste space if the enum values are non-contiguous, and won't cope with enum values that are too large for an `int`. I did say this example was very simple.

```
/// <summary>An array indexed by an Enum</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type stored in array</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="U">Indexer Enum type</typeparam>
public class ArrayByEnum<T,U> : IEnumerable where U : Enum // requires C# 7.3 or later
{
  private readonly T[] _array;
  private readonly int _lower;

  public ArrayByEnum()
  {
    _lower = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.GetValues(typeof(U)).Cast<U>().Min());
    int upper = Convert.ToInt32(Enum.GetValues(typeof(U)).Cast<U>().Max());
    _array = new T[1 + upper - _lower];
  }

  public T this[U key]
  {
    get { return _array[Convert.ToInt32(key) - _lower]; }
    set { _array[Convert.ToInt32(key) - _lower] = value; }
  }

  public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
  {
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(U)).Cast<U>().Select(i => this[i]).GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
ArrayByEnum<string,MyEnum> myArray = new ArrayByEnum<string,MyEnum>();
myArray[MyEnum.First] = "Hello";

myArray[YourEnum.Other] = "World"; // compiler error
```

Comment: Your answer works nicely. It gives write access to the elements in the array. The other generic answer (Caster class by @Matthew Whited) gives read only, so you must initialize the array with instances, and afterwards you cannot change an instance (only write in it). MyTable[Seat.East] = new Player { Name = "Joe", ID = 1234 };
However his Caster Deserializes bettter. I had an exception problem with Deserialization (NewtonSoft) with your solution.

Comment: Very cool generic solution here. I am using it in my project. Only thing I added was made it IEnumerable<T> instead of IEnumerable, as it gives ability to use the useful ling functions.

Answer (score 8):

You could make a class or struct that could do the work for you

---

```
public class Caster
{
    public enum DayOfWeek
    {
        Sunday = 0,
        Monday,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday,
        Saturday
    }

    public Caster() {}
    public Caster(string[] data) { this.Data = data; }

    public string this[DayOfWeek dow]{
        get { return this.Data[(int)dow]; }
    }

    public string[] Data { get; set; }


    public static implicit operator string[](Caster caster) { return caster.Data; }
    public static implicit operator Caster(string[] data) { return new Caster(data); }

}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Caster message_array = new string[7];
        Console.Write(message_array[Caster.DayOfWeek.Sunday]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

For lack of a better place to put this, I am posting a generic version of the Caster class below.  Unfortunately, it relies on runtime checks to enforce TKey as an enum.

```
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Weekend,
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday,
    Tuesday,
    Wednesday,
    Thursday,
    Friday,
    Saturday
}

public class TypeNotSupportedException : ApplicationException
{
    public TypeNotSupportedException(Type type)
        : base(string.Format("The type \"{0}\" is not supported in this context.", type.Name))
    {
    }
}

public class CannotBeIndexerException : ApplicationException
{
    public CannotBeIndexerException(Type enumUnderlyingType, Type indexerType)
        : base(
            string.Format("The base type of the enum (\"{0}\") cannot be safely cast to \"{1}\".",
                          enumUnderlyingType.Name, indexerType)
            )
    {
    }
}

public class Caster<TKey, TValue>
{
    private readonly Type baseEnumType;

    public Caster()
    {
        baseEnumType = typeof(TKey);
        if (!baseEnumType.IsEnum)
            throw new TypeNotSupportedException(baseEnumType);
    }

    public Caster(TValue[] data)
        : this()
    {
        Data = data;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get
        {
            var enumUnderlyingType = Enum.GetUnderlyingType(baseEnumType);
            var intType = typeof(int);
            if (!enumUnderlyingType.IsAssignableFrom(intType))
                throw new CannotBeIndexerException(enumUnderlyingType, intType);
            var index = (int) Enum.Parse(baseEnumType, key.ToString());
            return Data[index];
        }
    }

    public TValue[] Data { get; set; }


    public static implicit operator TValue[](Caster<TKey, TValue> caster)
    {
        return caster.Data;
    }

    public static implicit operator Caster<TKey, TValue>(TValue[] data)
    {
        return new Caster<TKey, TValue>(data);
    }
}

// declaring and using it.
Caster<DayOfWeek, string> messageArray =
    new[]
        {
            "Sunday",
            "Monday",
            "Tuesday",
            "Wednesday",
            "Thursday",
            "Friday",
            "Saturday"
        };
Console.WriteLine(messageArray[DayOfWeek.Sunday]);
Console.WriteLine(messageArray[DayOfWeek.Monday]);
Console.WriteLine(messageArray[DayOfWeek.Tuesday]);
Console.WriteLine(messageArray[DayOfWeek.Wednesday]);
Console.WriteLine(messageArray[DayOfWeek.Thursday]);
Console.WriteLine(messageArray[DayOfWeek.Friday]);
Console.WriteLine(messageArray[DayOfWeek.Saturday]);
```

Comment: +1, this, at least, encapsulates the pain of trying to shoehorn an enum into doing something it wasn't designed to (and shouldn't be used to) do.

Comment: Well, I would agree that something more sane should be done for the setters.  But I would never blanket it as something that "shouldn't be used." Another option would be to create custom readonly structs that are used in a similar fashion.

Comment: @Matthew Whited, I am probably over-reacting when I say "shouldn't be used," but I personally have never seen, and can't imagine, a good justifiable reason for creating an enum only to serve as an indexer in an array. I can say confidently that, in this limited case, you loose all of the benefits of an enum, and gain nothing in return.

Comment: As an exercise, you might try to make your solution generic.  I think it can be done, and would make it kick even more @$$.

Comment: Generics and Enums don't play very nice together.  But I agree that would be very cool.  If you used a class for the index instead you could use either an abstract base or an interface as the indexer type. But you would still have problems with the implicit conversions which would require a static factory method instead.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... You'd have to enforce the key as an enum at runtime. It's more code, but might still have use. Implicit casting should still work, though... I converted your code to generic for fun, but in reality, with all of the additional code, it probably performs more poorly than a dictionary. :(

Comment: You should post the code somewhere and link it here.  I'd like to see your solution.

Comment: I didn't know where else to put it, so I edited it in to your answer.

Comment: That would be much nicer if Enums and Generics played better.  It would be interesting to have generics work well with attributes and if interfaces such as INumeric existed in the current .Net (I know they can be faked with the DRL but that's just not the same)

Comment: @MichaelMeadows, what if you have solar system objects (Sun, Earth, Moon, etc.) you wish to be an enum to address when you hardcode their properties (name, mass, location, velocity, etc.)? Rather than accessing the array via 0, 1, 2, etc., it would be helpful to access them via Sun, Earth, Moon, etc. What is a more elegant solution? Keep in mind the values can be hardcoded as they are essentially constants.

Comment: Your answer provides a read only access to the elements in the array, so you must initialize the array the way you do (with instances). Afterwards you cannot replace an instance (only write in it). Cannot write `MyTable[Player.East] = new Player { Name = "Joe", ID = 1234 }`; However in the solution by @IanGoldby I had an exception problem with Deserialization (while yours works ok).

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
string[] message_array = Enum.GetNames(typeof(DaysOfTheWeek));
```

If you really need the length, then just take the .Length on the result :)
You can get values with:

```
string[] message_array = Enum.GetValues(typeof(DaysOfTheWeek));
```

Answer (score 5):

Compact form of enum used as index and assigning whatever type to a Dictionary
and strongly typed. In this case float values are returned but values could be complex Class instances having properties and methods and more:

```
enum opacityLevel { Min, Default, Max }
private static readonly Dictionary<opacityLevel, float> _oLevels = new Dictionary<opacityLevel, float>
{
    { opacityLevel.Max, 40.0 },
    { opacityLevel.Default, 50.0 },
    { opacityLevel.Min, 100.0 }
};

//Access float value like this
var x = _oLevels[opacitylevel.Default];
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is essentially a map, but don't want to incur performance overhead associated with  dictionary lookups, this might work:

```
    public class EnumIndexedArray<TKey, T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>> where TKey : struct
    {
        public EnumIndexedArray()
        {
            if (!typeof (TKey).IsEnum) throw new InvalidOperationException("Generic type argument is not an Enum");
            var size = Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Max()) + 1;
            Values = new T[size];
        }

        protected T[] Values;

        public static IEnumerable<TKey> Keys
        {
            get { return Enum.GetValues(typeof (TKey)).OfType<TKey>(); }
        }

        public T this[TKey index]
        {
            get { return Values[Convert.ToInt32(index)]; }
            set { Values[Convert.ToInt32(index)] = value; }
        }

        private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>> CreateEnumerable()
        {
            return Keys.Select(key => new KeyValuePair<TKey, T>(key, Values[Convert.ToInt32(key)]));
        }

        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, T>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return CreateEnumerable().GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
```

So in your case you could derive:

```
class DaysOfWeekToStringsMap:EnumIndexedArray<DayOfWeek,string>{};
```

Usage:

```
var map = new DaysOfWeekToStringsMap();

//using the Keys static property
foreach(var day in DaysOfWeekToStringsMap.Keys){
    map[day] = day.ToString();
}
foreach(var day in DaysOfWeekToStringsMap.Keys){
    Console.WriteLine("map[{0}]={1}",day, map[day]);
}

// using iterator
foreach(var value in map){
    Console.WriteLine("map[{0}]={1}",value.Key, value.Value);
}
```

Obviously this implementation is backed by an array, so non-contiguous enums like this:

```
enum
{
  Ok = 1,
  NotOk = 1000000
}
```

would result in excessive memory usage.

If you require maximum possible performance you might want to make it less generic and loose all generic enum handling code I had to use to get it to compile and work. I didn't benchmark this though, so maybe it's no big deal.

Caching the Keys static property might also help.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference the above problem can be summarized as follows:

I come from Delphi where you can define an array as follows:

```
type
  {$SCOPEDENUMS ON}
  TDaysOfTheWeek = (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday);

  TDaysOfTheWeekStrings = array[TDaysOfTheWeek];
```

Then you can iterate through the array using Min and Max:

```
for Dow := Min(TDaysOfTheWeek) to Max(TDaysOfTheWeek) 
  DaysOfTheWeekStrings[Dow] := '';
```

Though this is quite a contrived example, when you are dealing with array positions later in the code I can just type `DaysOfTheWeekStrings[TDaysOfTheWeek.Monday]`. This has the advantage of the fact that I should the `TDaysOfTheWeek` increase in size then I do not have to remember the new size of the array etc.....  However back to the C# world. I have found this example [C# Enum Array Example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-array).

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but there have been a number of comments about the fact that all solutions so far have run-time checks to ensure the data type is an enum.  Here is a complete solution (with some examples) of a solution with compile time checks (as well as some comments and discussions from my fellow developers)

```
//There is no good way to constrain a generic class parameter to an Enum.  The hack below does work at compile time,
//  though it is convoluted.  For examples of how to use the two classes EnumIndexedArray and ObjEnumIndexedArray,
//  see AssetClassArray below.  Or, e.g.
//      EConstraint.EnumIndexedArray<int, YourEnum> x = new EConstraint.EnumIndexedArray<int, YourEnum>();
//  See this post 
//      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79126/create-generic-method-constraining-t-to-an-enum/29581813#29581813
// and the answer/comments by Julien Lebosquain
public class EConstraint : HackForCompileTimeConstraintOfTEnumToAnEnum<System.Enum> { }//THIS MUST BE THE ONLY IMPLEMENTATION OF THE ABSTRACT HackForCompileTimeConstraintOfTEnumToAnEnum
public abstract class HackForCompileTimeConstraintOfTEnumToAnEnum<SystemEnum> where SystemEnum : class
{
    //For object types T, users should use EnumIndexedObjectArray below.
    public class EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, SystemEnum
    {
        //Needs to be public so that we can easily do things like intIndexedArray.data.sum()
        //   - just not worth writing up all the equivalent methods, and we can't inherit from T[] and guarantee proper initialization.
        //Also, note that we cannot use Length here for initialization, even if Length were defined the same as GetNumEnums up to
        //  static qualification, because we cannot use a non-static for initialization here.
        //  Since we want Length to be non-static, in keeping with other definitions of the Length property, we define the separate static
        //  GetNumEnums, and then define the non-static Length in terms of the actual size of the data array, just for clarity,
        //  safety and certainty (in case someone does something stupid like resizing data).
        public T[] data = new T[GetNumEnums()];

        //First, a couple of statics allowing easy use of the enums themselves.
        public static TEnum[] GetEnums()
        {
            return (TEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(TEnum));
        }
        public TEnum[] getEnums()
        {
            return GetEnums();
        }
        //Provide a static method of getting the number of enums.  The Length property also returns this, but it is not static and cannot be use in many circumstances.
        public static int GetNumEnums()
        {
            return GetEnums().Length;
        }
        //This should always return the same as GetNumEnums, but is not static and does it in a way that guarantees consistency with the member array.
        public int Length { get { return data.Length; } }
        //public int Count  { get { return data.Length; } }

        public EnumIndexedArray() { }

        // [WDS 2015-04-17] Remove. This can be dangerous. Just force people to use EnumIndexedArray(T[] inputArray).
        // [DIM 2015-04-18] Actually, if you think about it, EnumIndexedArray(T[] inputArray) is just as dangerous:
        //   For value types, both are fine.  For object types, the latter causes each object in the input array to be referenced twice,
        //   while the former causes the single object t to be multiply referenced.  Two references to each of many is no less dangerous
        //   than 3 or more references to one. So all of these are dangerous for object types.
        //   We could remove all these ctors from this base class, and create a separate
        //         EnumIndexedValueArray<T, TEnum> : EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum> where T: struct ...
        //   but then specializing to TEnum = AssetClass would have to be done twice below, once for value types and once
        //   for object types, with a repetition of all the property definitions.  Violating the DRY principle that much
        //   just to protect against stupid usage, clearly documented as dangerous, is not worth it IMHO.
        public EnumIndexedArray(T t)
        {
            int i = Length;
            while (--i >= 0)
            {
                this[i] = t;
            }
        }
        public EnumIndexedArray(T[] inputArray)
        {
            if (inputArray.Length > Length)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Length of enum-indexed array ({0}) to big. Can't be more than {1}.", inputArray.Length, Length));
            }
            Array.Copy(inputArray, data, inputArray.Length);
        }
        public EnumIndexedArray(EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum> inputArray)
        {
            Array.Copy(inputArray.data, data, data.Length);
        }

        //Clean data access
        public T this[int ac] { get { return data[ac]; } set { data[ac] = value; } }
        public T this[TEnum ac] { get { return data[Convert.ToInt32(ac)]; } set { data[Convert.ToInt32(ac)] = value; } }
    }


    public class EnumIndexedObjectArray<T, TEnum> : EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum>
        where TEnum : struct, SystemEnum
        where T : new()
    {
        public EnumIndexedObjectArray(bool doInitializeWithNewObjects = true)
        {
            if (doInitializeWithNewObjects)
            {
                for (int i = Length; i > 0; this[--i] = new T()) ;
            }
        }
        // The other ctor's are dangerous for object arrays
    }

    public class EnumIndexedArrayComparator<T, TEnum> : EqualityComparer<EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum>>
        where TEnum : struct, SystemEnum
    {
        private readonly EqualityComparer<T> elementComparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        public override bool Equals(EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum> lhs, EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum> rhs)
        {
            if (lhs == rhs)
                return true;
            if (lhs == null || rhs == null)
                return false;

            //These cases should not be possible because of the way these classes are constructed.
            // HOWEVER, the data member is public, so somebody _could_ do something stupid and make 
            // data=null, or make lhs.data == rhs.data, even though lhs!=rhs (above check)
            //On the other hand, these are just optimizations, so it won't be an issue if we reomve them anyway,
            // Unless someone does something really dumb like setting .data to null or resizing to an incorrect size,
            // in which case things will crash, but any developer who does this deserves to have it crash painfully...
            //if (lhs.data == rhs.data)
            //    return true;
            //if (lhs.data == null || rhs.data == null)
            //    return false;

            int i = lhs.Length;
            //if (rhs.Length != i)
            //    return false;
            while (--i >= 0)
            {
                if (!elementComparer.Equals(lhs[i], rhs[i]))
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode(EnumIndexedArray<T, TEnum> enumIndexedArray)
        {
            //This doesn't work: for two arrays ar1 and ar2, ar1.GetHashCode() != ar2.GetHashCode() even when ar1[i]==ar2[i] for all i (unless of course they are the exact same array object)
            //return engineArray.GetHashCode();
            //Code taken from comment by Jon Skeet - of course - in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244699/gethashcode-on-byte-array
            //31 and 17 are used commonly elsewhere, but maybe because everyone is using Skeet's post.
            //On the other hand, this is really not very critical.
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                int i = enumIndexedArray.Length;
                while (--i >= 0)
                {
                    hash = hash * 31 + elementComparer.GetHashCode(enumIndexedArray[i]);
                }
                return hash;
            }
        }
    }
}

//Because of the above hack, this fails at compile time - as it should.  It would, otherwise, only fail at run time.
//public class ThisShouldNotCompile : EConstraint.EnumIndexedArray<int, bool>
//{
//}

//An example
public enum AssetClass { Ir, FxFwd, Cm, Eq, FxOpt, Cr };
public class AssetClassArrayComparator<T> : EConstraint.EnumIndexedArrayComparator<T, AssetClass> { }
public class AssetClassIndexedArray<T> : EConstraint.EnumIndexedArray<T, AssetClass>
{
    public AssetClassIndexedArray()
    {
    }
    public AssetClassIndexedArray(T t) : base(t)
    {
    }
    public AssetClassIndexedArray(T[] inputArray) :  base(inputArray)
    {
    }
    public AssetClassIndexedArray(EConstraint.EnumIndexedArray<T, AssetClass> inputArray) : base(inputArray)
    {
    }

    public T Cm    { get { return this[AssetClass.Cm   ]; } set { this[AssetClass.Cm   ] = value; } }
    public T FxFwd { get { return this[AssetClass.FxFwd]; } set { this[AssetClass.FxFwd] = value; } }
    public T Ir    { get { return this[AssetClass.Ir   ]; } set { this[AssetClass.Ir   ] = value; } }
    public T Eq    { get { return this[AssetClass.Eq   ]; } set { this[AssetClass.Eq   ] = value; } }
    public T FxOpt { get { return this[AssetClass.FxOpt]; } set { this[AssetClass.FxOpt] = value; } }
    public T Cr    { get { return this[AssetClass.Cr   ]; } set { this[AssetClass.Cr   ] = value; } }
}

//Inherit from AssetClassArray<T>, not EnumIndexedObjectArray<T, AssetClass>, so we get the benefit of the public access getters and setters above
public class AssetClassIndexedObjectArray<T> : AssetClassIndexedArray<T> where T : new()
{
    public AssetClassIndexedObjectArray(bool bInitializeWithNewObjects = true)
    {
        if (bInitializeWithNewObjects)
        {
            for (int i = Length; i > 0; this[--i] = new T()) ;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
If you are using C# 7.3 or later, PLEASE don't use this ugly solution.  See Ian Goldby's answer from 2018.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do some extra mapping to get an array index of an enum value in a consistent and defined way:

```
int ArrayIndexFromDaysOfTheWeekEnum(DaysOfWeek day)
{
   switch (day)
   {
     case DaysOfWeek.Sunday: return 0;
     case DaysOfWeek.Monday: return 1;
     ...
     default: throw ...;
   }
}
```

Be as specific as you can. One day someone will modify your enum and the code will fail because the enum's value was (mis)used as an array index.

Comment: in this case it would make sense just to specify values in the Enum definition itself.

Comment: @van, you're right about this case, but there's some merit to @David Humpohl's assertion that the code might eventually fail. In the case of DaysOfWeek, the chances are low, but enums based on business values could change causing the underlying values to shift.

Answer (score 0):

It was a very good answer by @ian-goldby, but it didn't address the issue raised by @zar-shardan, which is an issue I hit myself. Below is my take on a solution, with a an extension class for converting an IEnumerable, and a test class below that:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// An array indexed by an enumerated type instead of an integer
/// </summary>
public class ArrayIndexedByEnum<TKey, TElement> : IEnumerable<TElement> where TKey : Enum
{
  private readonly Array _array;
  private readonly Dictionary<TKey, TElement> _dictionary;

  /// <summary>
  /// Creates the initial array, populated with the defaults for TElement
  /// </summary>
  public ArrayIndexedByEnum()
  {
    var min = Convert.ToInt64(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TKey)).Cast<TKey>().Min());
    var max = Convert.ToInt64(Enum.GetValues(typeof(TKey)).Cast<TKey>().Max());
    var size = max - min + 1;

    // Check that we aren't creating a ridiculously big array, if we are,
    // then use a dictionary instead
    if (min >= Int32.MinValue && 
        max <= Int32.MaxValue && 
        size < Enum.GetValues(typeof(TKey)).Length * 3L)
    {
      var lowerBound = Convert.ToInt32(min);
      var upperBound = Convert.ToInt32(max);
      _array = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(TElement), new int[] {(int)size }, new int[] { lowerBound });
    }
    else
    {
      _dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TElement>();
      foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TKey)).Cast<TKey>())
      {
        _dictionary[value] = default(TElement);
      }
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets the element by enumerated type
  /// </summary>
  public TElement this[TKey key]
  {
    get => (TElement)(_array?.GetValue(Convert.ToInt32(key)) ?? _dictionary[key]);
    set
    {
      if (_array != null)
      {
        _array.SetValue(value, Convert.ToInt32(key));
      }
      else
      {
        _dictionary[key] = value;
      }
    }
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Gets a generic enumerator
  /// </summary>
  public IEnumerator<TElement> GetEnumerator()
  {
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(TKey)).Cast<TKey>().Select(k => this[k]).GetEnumerator();
  }

  System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
  {
    return GetEnumerator();
  }
}
```

Here's the extension class:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Extensions for converting IEnumerable<TElement> to ArrayIndexedByEnum
/// </summary>
public static class ArrayIndexedByEnumExtensions
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a ArrayIndexedByEnumExtensions from an System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
  /// according to specified key selector and element selector functions.
  /// </summary>
  public static ArrayIndexedByEnum<TKey, TElement> ToArrayIndexedByEnum<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector) where TKey : Enum
  {
    var array = new ArrayIndexedByEnum<TKey, TElement>();
    foreach(var item in source)
    {
      array[keySelector(item)] = elementSelector(item);
    }
    return array;
  }
  /// <summary>
  /// Creates a ArrayIndexedByEnum from an System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable
  /// according to a specified key selector function.
  /// </summary>
  public static ArrayIndexedByEnum<TKey, TSource> ToArrayIndexedByEnum<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector) where TKey : Enum
  {
    return source.ToArrayIndexedByEnum(keySelector, i => i);
  }
}
```

And here are my tests:

```cs
[TestClass]
public class ArrayIndexedByEnumUnitTest
{
  private enum OddNumbersEnum : UInt16
  {
    One = 1,
    Three = 3,
    Five = 5,
    Seven = 7,
    Nine = 9
  }

  private enum PowersOf2 : Int64
  {
    TwoP0 = 1,
    TwoP1 = 2,
    TwoP2 = 4,
    TwoP3 = 8,
    TwoP4 = 16,
    TwoP5 = 32,
    TwoP6 = 64,
    TwoP7 = 128,
    TwoP8 = 256,
    TwoP9 = 512,
    TwoP10 = 1_024,
    TwoP11 = 2_048,
    TwoP12 = 4_096,
    TwoP13 = 8_192,
    TwoP14 = 16_384,
    TwoP15 = 32_768,
    TwoP16 = 65_536,
    TwoP17 = 131_072,
    TwoP18 = 262_144,
    TwoP19 = 524_288,
    TwoP20 = 1_048_576,
    TwoP21 = 2_097_152,
    TwoP22 = 4_194_304,
    TwoP23 = 8_388_608,
    TwoP24 = 16_777_216,
    TwoP25 = 33_554_432,
    TwoP26 = 67_108_864,
    TwoP27 = 134_217_728,
    TwoP28 = 268_435_456,
    TwoP29 = 536_870_912,
    TwoP30 = 1_073_741_824,
    TwoP31 = 2_147_483_648,
    TwoP32 = 4_294_967_296,
    TwoP33 = 8_589_934_592,
    TwoP34 = 17_179_869_184,
    TwoP35 = 34_359_738_368,
    TwoP36 = 68_719_476_736,
    TwoP37 = 137_438_953_472,
    TwoP38 = 274_877_906_944,
    TwoP39 = 549_755_813_888,
    TwoP40 = 1_099_511_627_776,
    TwoP41 = 2_199_023_255_552,
    TwoP42 = 4_398_046_511_104,
    TwoP43 = 8_796_093_022_208,
    TwoP44 = 17_592_186_044_416,
    TwoP45 = 35_184_372_088_832,
    TwoP46 = 70_368_744_177_664,
    TwoP47 = 140_737_488_355_328,
    TwoP48 = 281_474_976_710_656,
    TwoP49 = 562_949_953_421_312,
    TwoP50 = 1_125_899_906_842_620,
    TwoP51 = 2_251_799_813_685_250,
    TwoP52 = 4_503_599_627_370_500,
    TwoP53 = 9_007_199_254_740_990,
    TwoP54 = 18_014_398_509_482_000,
    TwoP55 = 36_028_797_018_964_000,
    TwoP56 = 72_057_594_037_927_900,
    TwoP57 = 144_115_188_075_856_000,
    TwoP58 = 288_230_376_151_712_000,
    TwoP59 = 576_460_752_303_423_000,
    TwoP60 = 1_152_921_504_606_850_000,
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestSimpleArray()
  {
    var array = new ArrayIndexedByEnum<OddNumbersEnum, string>();

    var odds = Enum.GetValues(typeof(OddNumbersEnum)).Cast<OddNumbersEnum>().ToList();

    // Store all the values
    foreach (var odd in odds)
    {
      array[odd] = odd.ToString();
    }

    // Check the retrieved values are the same as what was stored
    foreach (var odd in odds)
    {
      Assert.AreEqual(odd.ToString(), array[odd]);
    }
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestPossiblyHugeArray()
  {
    var array = new ArrayIndexedByEnum<PowersOf2, string>();

    var powersOf2s = Enum.GetValues(typeof(PowersOf2)).Cast<PowersOf2>().ToList();

    // Store all the values
    foreach (var powerOf2 in powersOf2s)
    {
      array[powerOf2] = powerOf2.ToString();
    }

    // Check the retrieved values are the same as what was stored
    foreach (var powerOf2 in powersOf2s)
    {
      Assert.AreEqual(powerOf2.ToString(), array[powerOf2]);
    }
  }
}
```