# GetHashCode() on byte[] array

Tags: c#, hash

What does `GetHashCode()` calculate when invoked on the `byte[]` array?
The 2 data arrays with equal content do not provide the same hash.

Comment: FYI: If you are on .NET4 ((IStructuralEquatable) myArray).GetHashCode(EqualityComparer<object>.Default) should give the same result for two arrays with same content. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.istructuralequatable.aspx.

Comment: Related: [why-does-.NET-not-implement-gethashcode-for-collections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907372/why-does-c-sharp-not-implement-gethashcode-for-collections)

Comment: @FuleSnabel Note that `IStructuralEquatable` requires use of the non-generic `IEqualityComparer` interface, which means that each `byte` in the array is going to be boxed during computation of the hashcode.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Like other non-primitive built-in types, it just returns something arbitrary.  It definitely doesn't try to hash the contents of the array.  See [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720177/default-implementation-for-object-gethashcode)

Answer (score 79):

Arrays in .NET don't override `Equals` or `GetHashCode`, so the value you'll get is basically based on reference equality (i.e. the default implementation in `Object`) - for value equality you'll need to roll your own code (or find some from a third party). You may want to implement `IEqualityComparer<byte[]>` if you're trying to use byte arrays as keys in a dictionary etc.

EDIT: Here's a reusable array equality comparer which should be fine so long as the array element handles equality appropriately. Note that you *mustn't* mutate the array after using it as a key in a dictionary, otherwise you won't be able to find it again - even with the same reference.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public sealed class ArrayEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[]>
{
    // You could make this a per-instance field with a constructor parameter
    private static readonly EqualityComparer<T> elementComparer
        = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    public bool Equals(T[] first, T[] second)
    {
        if (first == second)
        {
            return true;
        }
        if (first == null || second == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (first.Length != second.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < first.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!elementComparer.Equals(first[i], second[i]))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[] array)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            int hash = 17;
            foreach (T element in array)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + elementComparer.GetHashCode(element);
            }
            return hash;
        }
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        byte[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
        byte[] y = { 1, 2, 3 };
        byte[] z = { 4, 5, 6 };

        var comparer = new ArrayEqualityComparer<byte>();

        Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(x));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(y));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.GetHashCode(z));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(x, y));
        Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(x, z));
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chesnokov Yuriy: Okay, I've edited some code into my answer.

Comment: There seems to be [some debate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/468084/1149773) on whether `GetHashCode` should scan over the entire sequence. Interestingly, the [internal implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,807) for `Array.IStructuralEquatable.GetHashCode` only considers the last eight items of an array, sacrificing hash uniqueness for speed.

Comment: I did something similar using Enumerable.SequenceEqual(). Is there a particular reason to hand-code the element comparison? (Admittedly it's probably a bit faster.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: I don't *think* `SequenceEqual` is optimized to compare lengths first if the source implements appropriate interfaces.

Comment: @JonSkeet Since we have new primitives like `Memory<T>`, `Span<T>` or `Sequence<T>` can this code be optimised in any way? For example we do have `SequenceEqual` for `ReadOnlySpan<T>` now.

Comment: @bitbonk: I don't know whether that would be any faster - maybe; you'd need to run actual benchmarks for it. (It's possible that SequenceEqual is optimized to compare 8 bytes at a time, for example.)

Answer (score 15):

Simple solution

```
public static int GetHashFromBytes(byte[] bytes)
{
    return new BigInteger(bytes).GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: Seeing this solution made me smile. Clean, elegant. Digging deeper the hash implementation ends up calling https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Numerics/System/Numerics/NumericsHelpers.cs#L272

Comment: cough cough GetHashCode(); returns int32.

Comment: @XeorgeXeorge so?

Comment: @DaveJellison There is a `(2^32)` in 1 chance of collision, which is negalegible for most scenarios but is something that must be kept in mind whenever there's a hash code.

Comment: Agreed, but this is inherent with hashing as a rule. It's like going to the dictionary.com to complain about the definition of a word.

Comment: Note this method incurs a copy of the whole byte array, so may not be efficient. Also It's important to understand the purpose of GetHashCode() - it's not intended to produce a unique value but rather a well-distributed value for allocating buckets in a Dictionary or HashSet, which benefit from each bucket being roughly equal size. Both types use a combination of GetHashCode() and Equals() to determine whether a collision has really occurred.

Answer (score 13):

`byte[]` inherits `GetHashCode()` from `object`, it doesn't override it. So what you get is basically `object`'s implementation.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .NET 6 or at least .NET Core 2.1, you can write less codes and achieve better performance with [System.HashCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode) struct.

Using the method [HashCode.AddBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.addbytes) which available from .NET 6:

```cs
public int GetHashCode(byte[] value)
{
    var hash = new HashCode();
    hash.AddBytes(value);
    return hash.ToHashCode();
}
```

Using the method [HashCode.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.add) which available from .NET Core 2.1:

```cs
public int GetHashCode(byte[] value) =>
    value.Aggregate(new HashCode(), (hash, i) => {
        hash.Add(i);
        return hash;
    }).ToHashCode();
```

Note in the document of [HashCode.AddBytes()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode.addbytes?view=net-6.0#remarks=) it says:

> This method does not guarantee that the result of adding a span of bytes will match the result of adding the same bytes individually.

In this [sharplab demo](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgPgAgJgIwFgBQcAMACOSB0AMgJZQCOA3OunAMy4LYDC2A3utp7vXgGzalg2AOIBTYAAkAhgGcAFkwD2AE1FIAFACMAnsFEBtALrYAblIA2EUQEoOXdmi5PTUsNjmy52ALzYoogHdsaXklVXVrKkdnTg95fABBZWUAIV1RGXUzSxsomM44AHZ3T3wAFUUQhRVRCLyuAF87Ap4kfkERcSqw0QQtdKMXHOsfAD5m52yrRIBzGbBRGak9dX8g7pqIgBpsdTi5HeIR71G2CfyS+KTldSP6i4Li/fvnButyys8euupogoRGA4LmY3FIfH5AtgdHpBqwkFsEFtaA0Xk4QVDwWsoQNjHCEUiUecuOiAMaYyHQgy4+G0BGEv7OPAATnUYkkXxqGik1kiRIKSBZbI2qg0mh5qK4zNZXQ5IvUJPFfNwAul7NCNT63N5DKcUqFst6WkVOslKv16tUfQV2qcTTQDSAA=) they are just output same result, but this might be varying from .NET version or runtime environment.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not the same instance, it will return different hashes. I'm guessing it is based on the memory address where it is stored somehow.

Comment: no, it is not the same instance, I presume in that case hashes would be equal