# Compare if two sequences are equal

Tags: c#, ienumerable, yield

Before marking this as duplicate because of its title please consider the following short program:

```
static void Main()
{
    var expected = new List<long[]> { new[] { Convert.ToInt64(1), Convert.ToInt64(999999) } };
    var actual = DoSomething();
    if (!actual.SequenceEqual(expected)) throw new Exception();
}

static IEnumerable<long[]> DoSomething()
{
    yield return new[] { Convert.ToInt64(1), Convert.ToInt64(999999) };
}
```

I have a method which returns a sequence of arrays of type long. To test it I wrote some test-code similar to that one within `Main`.

However I get the exception, but I don´t know why. Shouldn´t the expected sequence be comparable to the actually returned one or did I miss anything?

To me it looks as both the method and the `epxected` contain exactly one single element containing an array of type long, doesn´t it?

EDIT: So how do I achieve to not get the exception meaning to compare the elements within the enumeration to return equality?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: The elements in your sequence are `long[]`. The comparison will be that of array references, which are indeed different. The elements of the array (which is in the sequence) will not be compared.

Comment: You should implement your own comparer and should pass an instance of this comparer as the second parameter to SequenceCompare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The actual problem is the fact that you're comparing two `long[]`, and `Enumerable.SequenceEquals` will use an `ObjectEqualityComparer<Int64[]>` (you can see that by examining `EqualityComparer<long[]>.Default` which is what is being internally used by `Enumerable.SequenceEquals`), which will compare references of those two arrays, and not the actual *values* stored inside the array, which obviously aren't the same.

To get around this, you could write a custom `EqualityComparer<long[]>`:

```
static void Main()
{
    var expected = new List<long[]> 
                       { new[] { Convert.ToInt64(1), Convert.ToInt64(999999) } };
    var actual = DoSomething();

    if (!actual.SequenceEqual(expected, new LongArrayComparer()))
        throw new Exception();
}

public class LongArrayComparer : EqualityComparer<long[]>
{
    public override bool Equals(long[] first, long[] second)
    {
        return first.SequenceEqual(second);
    }

    // GetHashCode implementation in the courtesy of @JonSkeet
    // from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244699/gethashcode-on-byte-array
    public override int GetHashCode(long[] arr)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            if (array == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int hash = 17;
            foreach (long element in arr)
            {
                hash = hash * 31 + element.GetHashCode();
            }

            return hash;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `GetHashCode` is incorrect. It'll work fine with this particular use, because `SequenceEqual` doesn't use `GetHashCode`, but if anyone used that for another use of `EqualityComparer<long[]>` like `Distinct` it would be incorrect. You need to produce a hash code that relates to sequence equality.

Comment: @JonHanna You're right, this was a quick hack just to show that one could easily implement a custom comparer. I'll fix it up.

Comment: What a luck I implemented a generic `EqualityComparer` some months ago whereas I can use lambda-expressions for implementing the two methods. However I´ll basically use exactly this approach now, thank you.

Comment: Yeah. No harm as a quicky, but worth pointing out in case someone copy-pastes it to where it won't work.

Comment: @JonHanna This one should be better.

Comment: You can and should move some code out of the unchecked block. Only have what's needed there.

Comment: @ErikE Do explain why that is of such importance?

Comment: Code is written for programmers, not computers. Thus, unusual code should be doing something unusual, otherwise the next person looking at it will waste time fruitlessly trying to figure out what is going on. In this case, the non-needed code being inside the unchecked block forces the reader to scan the whole block looking for the reason. And someone's modification later might accidentally put more code inside that block, too. It's about the signal-to-noise ratio. It's about keeping the surface area of "this is weird code" small.

Answer (score 4):

`SequenceEquals` tests for the elements within the sequences to be identical. The elements within the enumerations are of type `long[]`, so we actually compare two different arrays (containing the same elements however) against each other which is obsiously done by comparing their references instead of their actual value .

So what we actually check here is this `expected[0] == actual[0]` instead of `expected[0].SequqnceEquals(actual[0])`

This is obiosuly returns `false` as both arrays share different references.

If we flatten the hierarchy using `SelectMany` we get what we want:

```
if (!actual.SelectMany(x => x).SequenceEqual(expected.SelectMany(x => x))) throw new Exception();
```

EDIT:

Based on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34155035/2528063) I found another elegant way to check if all the elements from `expected` are contained in `actual` also:

```
if (!expected.All(x => actual.Any(y => y.SequenceEqual(x)))) throw new Exception();
```

This will search if for ever sub-list within `expected` there is a list within `actual` that is sequentially identical to the current one. This seems much smarter to be as we do not need any custom `EqualityComparer` and no weird hashcode-implementation.

Answer (score 4):

No, your sequences are *not* equal!

Lets remove the sequence bit, and just take what is in the *first element* of each item

```
var firstExpected = new[] { Convert.ToInt64(1), Convert.ToInt64(999999) };
var firstActual = new[] { Convert.ToInt64(1), Convert.ToInt64(999999) };
Console.WriteLine(firstExpected == firstActual); // writes "false"
```

The code above is comparing two *separate arrays* for equality. Equality does not check the contents of arrays it checks the references for equality.

Your code using `SequenceEquals` is, essentially, doing the same thing. It checks the references in each case of each element in an enumerable.

Comment: Yeap, actually found that out one second ago. However my solution does not really seem convenient to me, do you have a better one?

Comment: @Yuval's answer contains the right way. No point me re-writing that.