# Linq, determine if list are equals

Tags: c#, linq

How to determine, if items in a `List<List<int>>` are equals ?

```
List<List<int>> equals = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>() { 1,2 },
    new List<int>() { 1,2 }
};

List<List<int>> notEquals = new List<List<int>>()
{
    new List<int>() { 1,2 },
    new List<int>() { 2,500}
};
```

Comment: Are lists `{1, 2}` and `{2, 1}` equal or not? Does order matter?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko order does not matter.

Comment: @SergiiZhevzhyk . No duplicate. In my example, i have only 2 items, but eventually more

Comment: @BobyOneKenobi: in that case the accepted Tim Schmelter's answer is *not* the one you're looking for: `SequenceEqual` *depends* on order.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to compare the first list with all others, you can use `SequenceEqual`:

```
List<int> first = yourLists[0];
bool allEqual = yourLists.Skip(1).All(l => first.SequenceEqual(l));
```

Since `All` returns `false` on the first unequal list this is pretty efficient.

Comment: Good. But isn't this works? `bool allEqual = first.SequenceEqual(yourLists[1]);`

Comment: @user2946329: if the list can only contain two sub-lists that works too. But my approach works even if it contains more than two. You are comparing only the first with the second list. What if there's a third list which is unequal?

Comment: Right. So your answer is more comprehensive.