# Do C++ enums Start at 0?

Tags: c++, enums, language-lawyer, enumeration, ordinal

If I have an `enum` that does not assign numbers to the enumerations, will its ordinal value be 0? For example:

```
enum enumeration { ZERO,
                   ONE,
                   TWO,
                   THREE,
                   FOUR,
                   FIVE,
                   SIX,
                   SEVEN,
                   EIGHT,
                   NINE };
```

I've been able to find a [post citing that the C99 standard requires a 0 ordinal number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30312219/2642059). But I know C++ ignores several things in the [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) standard. And I've also been able to find a [post witnessing the compiler using an ordinal value of 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/404253/2642059), something I also seem recall seeing, though I can't say how long ago that was.

I would really like to see an answer that confirms this for C++, but I'd also like to know if an ordinal 0 holds *even if* I specify a value in the middle of an `enum`:

```
enum enumeration { ZERO,
                   ONE,
                   TWO,
                   THREE = 13,
                   FOUR,
                   FIVE,
                   SIX,
                   SEVEN,
                   EIGHT,
                   NINE };
```

Comment: The next enumeration constant will always have the value of the previous one in the list. So in your case you would get `0, 1, 2, 13, 14, 15...`. Note that this could create duplicates.

Comment: @Jonathan Mee  It would be very strange if enumerators in C++ opposite to C do not start from 0.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I agree, and obviously from the answers that is the case. I just couldn't find anything that guaranteed it for C++. And I don't want to keep specifying an ordinal 0 if I don't need to :S

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this rule wasn't changed in C99. That is, its the way it was since C began.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Per that standard [dcl.enum]

> The enumeration type declared with an enum-key of only enum is an unscoped enumeration, and its enumerators are unscoped enumerators. The enum-keys enum class and enum struct are semantically equivalent; an enumeration type declared with one of these is a scoped enumeration, and its enumerators are scoped
> enumerators. The optional identifier shall not be omitted in the declaration of a scoped enumeration. The type-specifier-seq of an enum-base shall name an integral type; any cv-qualification is ignored. An opaqueenum-declaration declaring an unscoped enumeration shall not omit the enum-base. The identifiers in an enumerator-list are declared as constants, and can appear wherever constants are required. An enumeratordefinition with = gives the associated enumerator the value indicated by the constant-expression. **If the first
> enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero.** An enumerator-definition without an initializer gives the enumerator the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous enumerator by one.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

So yes, if you do not specify a start value, it will default to 0.

> I would really like to see an answer that confirms this for C++, but I'd also like to know if an ordinal 0 holds even if I specify a value in the middle of an enum:

This also works.  It will start at 0 and increment up along the way.  Then after the enum you assign the value to it will begin to increase by one from that value for subsequent enumerator.

Comment: Similar for C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434105/are-default-enum-values-in-c-the-same-for-all-compilers

Answer (score 33):

From the C++11 specification (7.2/2):

> If the first *enumerator* has no *initializer*, the value of the corresponding constant is zero. An *enumerator-definition* without an *initializer* gives the *enumerator* the value obtained by increasing the value of the previous *enumerator* by one.

So yes, the first identifier in the enumeration will have the value zero (if it's not explicitly initialized to another value), and each consecutive identifier will have the value of the previous plus one.

Answer (score 8):

From § 7.2, page 165:

> . If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero

Source: *[Working draft: Standard for programming language C++](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2015/n4527.pdf)*