# Is it possible to define a macro that defines an enum class and GetCount() method returning the count of enum elements?

Tags: c++, c++17

I was able to define macro that defines an old-style enum and GetCount() method returning the count of enum elements:

```
#define DEFINE_FLAGS_ENUM(EnumName, ...) \
struct EnumName { \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
    static constexpr std::size_t GetCount() { return std::max({__VA_ARGS__}) + 1;} \
};
```

With enum class my first idea was:

```
template <class T> struct EnumTraits;

#define NDA_FLAGS_ENUM(EnumName, ...) \
enum class EnumName { __VA_ARGS__ }; \
template<> struct EnumTraits<EnumName> { static constexpr std::size_t GetCount() { return std::max({__VA_ARGS__}) + 1; }};
```

but this does not compile, because **VA_ARGS** should be prepended with 'EnumName::'.

Comment: [`BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/preprocessor/doc/ref/tuple_size.html)?

Comment: @Quentin explain please.

Comment: Well, `BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE((__VA_ARGS__))` will give you the number of arguments passed to your macro.

Comment: @Quentin yes, BOOST_PP_TUPLE_SIZE is a solution. But its implementation is a bit terrible.

Comment: Preprocessor metaprogramming is quite terrible as a whole, hence the library ;)

Comment: You have a more fundamental problem than VA_ARGS. `enum class` values do not have arithmetic meaning, so `std::max` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @Frank my own version of std::max will help.

Comment: This all seems a bit overkill; is a simple `enum {x_a, x_b, x_c, x_count};` not sufficient?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It may not be, e.g. consider `enum {a = -1, b, c, count};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**enum**

As suggested in comments, as for your first macro `DEFINE_FLAGS_ENUM`, `std::max` does not seem to work.
Thus I propose an alternative way for it.

Since our `enum` is defined as an anonymous one in the class `EnumName`, we can define the tuple of them and detect the size of it at compile-time as follows.
So this macro would well work for you:

```
#include <tuple>

#define DEFINE_FLAGS_ENUM(EnumName, ...)                  \
struct EnumName                                           \
{                                                         \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ };                                 \
                                                          \
    static constexpr std::size_t GetCount()               \
    {                                                     \
        using T = decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__)); \
        return std::tuple_size<T>::value;                 \
    }                                                     \
};
```

---

**enum class**

For the `enum class`, we can reuse the above method as follows.
Here, instead of counting the elements of enum class, we again count the ones of *enum* which is hidden in the class `EnumTraits<EnumName>` as a private member:

```
#include <tuple>

template <class T> struct EnumTraits;

#define NDA_FLAGS_ENUM(EnumName, ...)                     \
enum class EnumName { __VA_ARGS__ };                      \
template<>                                                \
struct EnumTraits<EnumName>                               \
{                                                         \
private:                                                  \
    enum { __VA_ARGS__ };                                 \
                                                          \
public:                                                   \
    static constexpr std::size_t GetCount()               \
    {                                                     \
        using T = decltype(std::make_tuple(__VA_ARGS__)); \
        return std::tuple_size<T>::value;                 \
    }                                                     \
};
```

---

Then we can define an enum and enum class as follows:

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VvxZHlmWr9oXuskV)

```
// enum.
DEFINE_FLAGS_ENUM(Animal, Dog, Cat)
static_assert(Animal::GetCount() == 2);

// enum class.
NDA_FLAGS_ENUM(Vehicle, Car, Train, AirPlain)
static_assert(EnumTraits<Vehicle>::GetCount() == 3);
```

Comment: Probably, we can also create std::initializer_list<int> values and do values.end() - values.begin().

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky thx. Yes, but then `end` and `begin` must be `constexpr` ones because `GetCount()` is `constexpr`. I think that an another way is counting `','` in the string literal `#__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: They are consexpr as far as I see.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Ah Yes. And my first post (now edited) did take similar approach with the *extended constexpr*, `for(auto& i : {_VA_ARGS__}) {...}` :).

Comment: And even more simple: we can add Count to the private enum: private: enum { __VA_ARGS__, Count }; \ (but leave enum class as is).

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky Ah, nice idea :). [dcl.enum] in the C++ standard states *If the first enumerator has no initializer, the value of the corresponding constant is zero*. So that well works. I found the same discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811486/do-c-enums-start-at-0).