# Using enum as a condition, what will the if condition return, True or False?

Tags: c++

```
enum segment
{
  OFF,
  ON
};

int main()
{
  segment indicator;
  int temp_prev = 37;
  int temp_curr = 39;
  indicator = OFF;

  if ((temp_curr > temp_prev and temp_curr > 39) or !indicator)
  {}
```

This is part of a basic program to understand the use and properties of `enum`.

What confuses me is, what does `!enum` return, and what will the `if` condition return?

Comment: Here's a description of [how `enum`s start at zero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34811571/1270789), so effectively `OFF` is zero and `ON` is one. However, using an `enum` as a boolean is confusing; I'd recommend `bool indicatorIsOn;` as a better naming.

Comment: Your code is not a good [mre]. and an optimizing C++ compiler is allowed to transform it into an empty `main`. Read e.g. [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming C) An enum is [stored as an int](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.7.2.2.html). In your example, OFF would default to zero, which is treated as false in a conditional, any non-zero value would be considered true.

Answer (score 1):

> what confuses me is what does `!enum` return

Unary `!` is the logical NOT operator. The enum value implicitly converts to the underlying integer type. The result is true if that integer is 0, and false otherwise. The underlying value of `OFF` is 0, therefore the result is true in this case, and so is the entire condition.